# serverless-pseudo-parameter plugin depracation

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

Recently serverless-pseudo-parameters plugin got depracated. Got to know that features are covered in serverless framework post version 2.50.0. I'm using this pseudo-parameters plugin, now that this is depracated, what are the changes to be done to let the application know that it has to use the serverless framework features ?
I use resources like #{AWS:Region} etc. which has to be replaced by ${aws:region} it seems. Similarly what are the complete set of changes that I have to do ? Is there any documentation available on this ?